# Automated Lottery and Prize Distribution

Tags: php, mysql, automation, business-logic, business-rules

We are trying to build a system in which the winners of prizes are selected on a daily basis and their relevant contact details (address, phone #, name) are pulled from database. The number of prizes is fixed, but can change on a daily basis if new prizes are added to the db. This is part of a quiz system, so we have determined that a user's odds of  winning a getting daily prize is the:

**# of sessions they have completed/ # of total sessions completed by all the users**

Once a user has won a prize, their # of completed sessions is reset to 1. This is to ensure that people that have not won before have a greater chance of winning. Users are only eligible to win a daily prize if they have participated that day and attempted a certain amount of questions (10).

**Is the proposed logic flawed? If not, how does one implement this logic into our automated system?**

Comment: Hi! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The logic sounds achievable, though whether it offers the right odds for your business model is up to you. Presumably you want to strike a balance between giving people reasonable odds of winning whilst not having to pay out so much you run out of money. How to implement the logic is a very broad question. Do you have a database design? If so, try writing a script that calculates the things you need (e.g. total sessions completed by all users). Then you can loop through all users and determine whether they have won or not.

Comment: What exact information do you need regarding the database design?